# jClouds: Is it safe to use only one BlobStore

Tags: java, jclouds

I am new to jClouds projects. I am creating a library, which will access multiple cloud providers and filesystem. I wonder, what is the difference between BlobStore and BlobStoreContext? Consider I have the following dao:

```
@Inject
private BlobStoreContext blobStoreContext;

@Override
public String storeMedia(String customerId, byte[] media) {
    BlobStore blobStore = blobStoreContext.getBlobStore();

    String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    Blob blob = blobStore.blobBuilder(id)
            .payload(media)
            .contentLength(media.length)
            .build();
    blobStore.putBlob(customerId, blob);

    return id;
}
```

DAO is a singleton object. Should I inject BlobStoreContext and get a new BlobStore on every invocation, or is just ok to @Inject the BlobStore and use it as a singleton instance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A context configures a connection to a particular provider, so if you need your DAO to be able to persist data for N providers, you need to configure it in a way that can access the right context for each operation. If your DAO is scoped to just one provider then you can have the context or BlobStore directly injected.

You can read a quick intro to the main jclouds concepts here:
http://jclouds.apache.org/start/concepts/